# How can I insert the HTML5 canvas inside the post limits?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, blogger, p5.js

I'm experimenting with JavaScript inside Blogger. It works. But I don't know how to relocate the canvas, since it appears at the bottom of the page. I want it to be "inside a post". You can take a look. I want the canvas inline, just below the post title (Muerte).

http://safetyinsolitude.blogspot.mx/p/muerte.html

Like, is it even possible?

Also, for the js part, I'm using p5.js. Tho simple, maybe I can put something inside.

HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.4.12/p5.js"></script>
<script src="p5/addons/play/lib/p5.play.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<!--<script language="javascript" src="../addons/p5.sound.js"></script>-->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://googledrive.com/host/0B6EuBapi745ZOXIycnNGX0s4UHM"></script>

<title>Muerte y seducción</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

JS code:

```
function setup() {
  // uncomment this line to make the canvas the full size of the window
  createCanvas(640, 480);
}

function draw() {
  // draw stuff here
  fill(random(255), random(255), random(255));
  text("Dante mamabergas", mouseX, mouseY);
  ellipse(width/2, height/2, random(200), random(200));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the parent() method to place the canvas within a particular div.
http://p5js.org/reference/#p5.Element/parent

Answer (score 1):

after calling create canvas:

> function setup() {   // uncomment this line to make the canvas the
>   full size of the window   createCanvas(640, 480); }

just use
`document.querySelector(".hentry").insertBefore(document.getElementById("defaultCanvas"),document.querySelector(".hentry .post-header"));`

it's ugly but it's either that or changing the p5.js

Comment: Interesting solution. The other one was simpler, but I'll try this too just in case. Thanks.